# Hide div when custom field is empty

Tags: html, field, hide

I'm trying to hide a div when the custom field is empty. When I don't use an image in the "palette" custom field I want it to hide `<div class="small-12 large-12 columns center">`. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="small-12 large-12 columns center">
  <?php 
    $image = get_field('palette');
      if( !empty($image) ): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The classes on the div have padding and margins assigned to them which is creating the spacing. Removing the div all together when will remove the classes solving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the if statement around the whole div, like this:

```
    <?php 
    $image = get_field('palette');
    if( !empty($image) ): 
    ?>
        <div class="small-12 large-12 columns center">
               <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
        </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: How would that work with two custom fields in the same div.. 

`<div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns center logo-desc">
<h4><?php the_field('logo-title'); ?></h4>
 
<p><?php the_field('logo-desc'); ?></p>

</div>`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide the div you should do this :

```
     <div class="small-12 large-12 columns center"
<?php 
$image = get_field('palette');
if (empty($image)){?>style="display:none"<?php } ?>
>
  <?php 
    $image = get_field('palette');
      if( !empty($image) ): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: How would that work with two custom fields in the same div.. 

`<div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns center logo-desc"> 

<h4><?php the_field('logo-title'); ?></h4> 
<p><?php the_field('logo-desc'); ?></p> 
</div>`